# Excel Like Borders

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

How in SSRS can I set custom borders like the below?  I am sure a custom function could be utilized to create this feel and effect, but I am not advanced enough to know that.  I tried just using the properties window to set it up as such, but that did not work either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set individual border widths at a textbox level by selectin an individual textbox, then expanding the **BorderWidth** property and setting the individual sides as required.

A textbox with settings like:

[image]

Will appear as:

[image]

Which matches one of your examples. Other textboxes will require different individual settings to match your differing requirements.

I would note that SSRS is temperamental when rendering borders in different renderers and zoom levels, so even if it looks perfect in one setting it might be slightly off in another, but hopefully this works for you.

Comment: AH, I didn't try a box by box set.  I was doing row by row and column by column.  Wasn't quite working out for me that way.  Let me give this a twirl and see how it works.

Comment: That works perfectly.  Is there a way of creating a template matrix somehow, as I will need these same settings applied to multiple tables?  Or a custom function that could create all of this quickly.

Comment: Well, not really, at least that I'm aware of. SSRS is notoriously poor at things like templating or defining styles to be shared between and within reports. You can look at http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/creating-a-custom-report-template-in-ssrs.html for some rudimentary templating ideas, but this is report level only, and https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-with-style/ is a useful primer on hacks to get centralised styling in SSRS, but you can see all the methods are pretty terrible. You might find better answers out there though, so good luck.